# Playing .wav data of any format in Mac C++ program, similar to win32 PlaySound

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, wav, playback

I have .wav files that have been stored in a central database.  I need to play them in Mac C++ code.  The .wav files have lots of different formats - some of them are quite old - for example 4bit.

I got code using AudioHardware interfaces to work for the main formats.  But, these work only if the sample rate in the .wav is accepted by the audio unit.

I need something similar to win32 PlaySound where I just give it the buffer containing the .wav file, and it performs the necessary conversions.

I need the playback to occur either synchronously, or asynchronously.

I get lost trying to read the apple developer docs - there are so many different levels, and the overviews are really poor!  Should I be looking at Audio Queue?  Audio File?  QuickTime?

Thanks in advance for any pointers!

Answer (score 2):

I you are developing in 10.5, then AudioQueues are the API you want.  They aren't as easy as a single function, but they do provide a fairly comprehensive high level API for playing all kinds of sound files.

The [Audio Queue Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/AudioQueueProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005343-CH1-SW1) goes through a detailed example of using it for playback, and covers the functions and structures you will need to provide.

I can't vouch for the quality of this [sample](http://www.idevgames.com/forum/showthread.php?t=15280), but it does show a simple Obj-C wrapper for playing background music that should be enough to get you past the documentation wall.

Good luck!